# My computeAverage function is not returning value c++

Tags: c++, arrays

The problem I am facing is my computeAverage() function is not calculating the average of marks.

// computeAverage receives the array with the test scores, and its size, 
// as paramaters, computes the average and returns the average value.
// Uses the local variable average to store temporary and final values.
// Uses a for iteration control structure to add all values in the array,
// and store the sum in average. ONLY 1 variable declared in this method.

```
int computeAverage(const int anArray[], const int arraySize)
{
    // declare the local integer variable average and initialize to 0
    int average = 0;
    // create a for iteration control structure to add all values in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        average += anArray[i];
    }
    // the intermediate results are stored in average
    average = average / arraySize;

    // return the average value
    return average;
}
```

I have used this `computeAverage(&theScores[arraySize], arraySize)` to call the function

Comment: `computeAverage(&theScores[arraySize], arraySize)` --> `computeAverage(theScores, arraySize)`.  Original code is accessing from one beyond the last element of the array.

Comment: To add to what @chux-ReinstateMonica said, you probably want to define `average` to have type `float` or `double` and change the return type accordingly, otherwise your average will be the nearest rounded down int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have used this `computeAverage(&theScores[arraySize], arraySize)` to call the function

Because you need to simply invoke it as

```
result = computeAverage(&theScores[0], arraySize);
```

Or more generally:

```
result = computeAverage(theScores, arraySize);
```

As you have it now, you are passing the set of elements past the end of your array, not the actual array start.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Got it